# Get DMMF: Unable to resolve path to query-engine binary

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, prisma, prisma-graphql

`Get DMMF: Unable to resolve the path to query-engine binary` When I tried to run the prisma:seed, I got the specified error.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Prisma CLI Version: 3.15.2
BE: GraphQL - NestJS

I recently upgrade the Ubuntu distribution to the 22.04 version and when I am trying to seed the data into the database I am getting the error.

Comment: Have you added binaryTargets with Linux attribute in your prisma schema? https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#linux-alpine